# (Unity)Text component does not show in menu

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, components

I have installed  unity 2021.3.14f1. But the problem is that the "UI>Text"does not shows in the menu below.
How to make the Text component shown in the menu?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to double-click on it after you added? Try to also check in the Game view if it is really not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old, non TextMeshPro text is under the Legacy option:
[Check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0zca.png)

Answer (score 1):

yeah now its call text mesh pro(tmp)
you can still access text through legacy > text, but might be obsolete in the future